# can regex capture groups be used in GNU find command?

Tags: find, regular-expression

With the GNU `find` command (*GNU findutils 4.4.2*), a regular expression can be used to search for files. For example:

```
$ find pool -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/mypackage-([a-zA-Z0-9.]+-[0-9]{1,2})-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz+"
```

Is it possible to extract the *capture group* defined by that expression and use it in a `-printf` argument?

So, given a found file called `pool/mypackage-1.4.9-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`, I would like to include the `1.4.9-1` part in a `printf` expression.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, but you can use `-print0` and pipe to GNU `sed -Ez` (possibly followed by `tr '\0' '\n'`)

Comment: Note that `[a-zA-Z]` only makes sense in the C/POSIX locale.

Comment: I expected the simple answer to be *No* given copious amounts of searching and reading man pages before asking the question. The answers provide interesting alternaive ways to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to l0b0's fine answer (shorter, but potentially slightly less efficient):

Assuming a (recent) GNU `sed`:

```
find pool -print0 |
  sed -znE 's|.*/mypackage-([[:alnum:].]+-[0-9]{1,2})-x86_64\.pkg\.tar\.xz$|\1|p'|
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Note the expensive part of `find` is the walking down the tree which it will have to do anyway whether you have `-regex` or not. So here, we're doing the matching and reporting in `sed` instead.

Comment: This works great. I changed the sed field separator to a colon so more complex expressions that I have which include pipes also work. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you use

```
find pool -regextype posix-extended \
    -regex ".*/mypackage-([a-zA-Z0-9.]+-[0-9]{1,2})-x86_64\.pkg\.tar\.xz" \
    -printf '%f\n' |
  grep -Eo '[a-zA-Z0-9.]+-[0-9]{1,2}'
```

(assuming GNU `grep` as well), it should work for any path. The regex doesn't allow for any newlines, so there's no way to make it match for example a directory containing a similar name.

Comment: Note that in this particular case, you could replace the `grep` with a `cut -d- -f2,3` to avoid the overhead of another regexp matching.

Comment: When I used this, I got newlines embedded because the `grep` expression matches two parts. I guess the expression could be fixed but using cut sorts it. However, it's brittle: say the file was `mypackage-other` the fied numbers would be out. The other answer may be less efficient (not really an issue here) but it does work.

Comment: Yep, just thought it was nice to reuse the regex exactly