# How to use regex inside exec with find?

Tags: find, regular-expression

Is it possible to use regular expressions based on the result (file name) inside the `exec` argument with `find`? I want to be able to "exec" based on parts of the argument, like:

`find . -name pattern -regex "foo (regex1) bar (Regex2)" -exec something $1 $2 ;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run find -exec?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a specific example. Of course it's possible, just run a tool with regex capabilities inside the `-exec`. We can't help you do it if you don't explain what you need though.

Comment: You can find inspiration here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139331/can-regex-capture-groups-be-used-in-gnu-find-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use capture groups from the regexp in the command to execute. If you use `find -regex` to restrict matches, you'll have to do some extra matching in the command. You can do that by invoking a shell and using its own pattern matching constructs. For example, if `foo` and `bar` are constant strings and `regex1` can't match `bar`:

```
find … -exec sh -c '
  x=${0#foo}
  y=${x#*bar}
  x=${x%%bar*}
  something "$x" "$y"
' {} \;
```

Invoking a shell has a little overhead. You can improve performance a bit by invoking the shell in batches.

```
find … -exec sh -c '
  for item do
    item=${item#foo}
    y=${item#*bar}
    x=${item%%bar*}
    something "$x" "$y"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Since you've already done some filtering, you may be able to get away with shell patterns that match more than `regex1` and `regex2`, but, for paths of that particular form, match the same part. If `foo` and `bar` can't be expressed with ordinary shell patterns, you can invoke ksh or bash, which support extra patterns that are as powerful as regular expressions: `@(alter|native)`, `*(zero-or-more)`, `+(one-or-more)`, `?(optional)`, and `!(negated)`. [In bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), these patterns need to be enabled with `shopt -s extglob`. In ksh, they are available natively.

In bash, there is a regular expression matching construct which you can use in [conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b): `[[ $STRING =~ REGEXP ]]`. The regexp is an ERE (like `find -regextype posix-egrep`). (Zsh has a similar one; ksh has `=~` but doesn't expose capture groups.) Capture groups are available via the `BASH_REMATCH` array.

```
find … -exec bash -c '
  for item do
    [[ item =~ foo(regex1)bar(regex2) ]]
    something "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  done
' bash {} +
```

An alternative approach is to [print out the result and filter it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139331/can-regex-capture-groups-be-used-in-gnu-find-command), then call `xargs` to invoke the program. Arrange to have the first and second argument as successive items and run `xargs -n 2`. Use null bytes as separators to avoid xargs's strange quoting format, or use `-d '\n'` to use strict line-by-line parsing. Recent GNU tools such as sed can work with null bytes instead of newlines to separate records.

```
find … -print0 |
sed -z 's/^foo\(regex1\)bar\(regex2\)$/\1\x00\2/'
| xargs -n2 -0 something
```

An alternative approach is to ditch find and use the recursive globbing feature of ksh93, bash or zsh: `**/` matches subdirectories recursively. This isn't possible for complex find expressions involving boolean connectors, but it's enough for most cases. For example, in bash (note that this recurses into symbolic links to directories, like `find -L`):

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
for x in **/*bar*; do
  if [[ item =~ foo(regex1)bar(regex2) ]]; then
    something "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  fi
done
```

In zsh:

```
for x in **/*bar*; do
  if [[ item =~ foo(regex1)bar(regex2) ]]; then
    something $match[1] $match[2]
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using zsh regex globbing: `for file in 'find . -name pattern' ; do cmd $file:s/foo/bar ; done` as it was easiest to remember (so I don't have to look it up next time).

Comment: @Emre If you have zsh, you (almost always) don't need find: `for file in **/foo(regex1)bar; do [[ file =~ … ]]; something $match[1] $match[2]; done`.

Comment: Indeed! Next time friends ask why I use zsh I can show this :)