# Regex not matching file using `find` despite being valid

Tags: find, regular-expression

I am attempting to run this `find` command to match files with a camelcased name, with the goal being to put a space between adjacent lower and upper case letters, but it's not matching anything:

```
find -E . -regex "([a-z])([A-Z])"
```

An example of a file I'm trying to match is

```
./250 - ErosPhiliaAgape.mp3
```

I've tested this regex on this file [here](https://regex101.com/r/wuvChQ/1) and it matches successfully.

What is it I'm doing wrong with my `find` command?

Comment: What operating system are you using? The `-E` is not a standard option.

Comment: Mac OS. The `-E` is for extended regex.

Comment: Yeah, I found it. In future, please remember to always mention your OS. GNU `find` (Linux) is not the same as BSD `find` (OSX`) which is not the same as POSIX `find`. Many of the standard tools behave differently in different *nix systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
find . -name "*[a-z][A-Z]*"
```

Comment: That works, but when I place the matched characters in a capture group like so "*([a-z])([A-Z])*" it doesn't match.

Comment: Find won't handle capture groups. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139331/can-regex-capture-groups-be-used-in-gnu-find-command

Comment: @ChrisWilson that's because the regex needs to match the entire path. The `-name` does not take regular expressions, [it takes globs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46444/22222), and that only needs top match the name.

Comment: @SYN actually, [as I just learned](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/regex-not-matching-file-using-find-despite-being-valid/332405?noredirect=1#comment585019_332405), GNU `find` *can* handle capture groups. Dunno about BSD/OSX `find`. In fact, that is very nicely demonstrated in the accepted answer to the question you linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Find's `-regex` matches the entire path, not just the file name. That means that to find `/path/to/foo`, you need `-regex`'.*foo'`, and not just`foo`. You want something like:

```
find  . -E -regex ".*[a-z][A-Z].*"
```

It would be much simpler to use globs and the simpler `-name`  as [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332401/22222) by SYN, however, instead of regexes.

Comment: @steeldriver wow. That's completely new to me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `([a-z])([A-Z])` does not match `./250 - ErosPhiliaAgape.mp3`.  In fact, `([a-z])([A-Z])` can only match exactly 2 characters -- `-regex` is an *anchored* match over the entire path.  If you want to use `-regex` to search for a file whose *name contains* a regex, you can write it like this (BSD/macOS `find` syntax):

```
find -E . -regex '.*/[^/]*([a-z])([A-Z])[^/]*'
```

The GNU find equivalent would be something like

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[^/]*([a-z])([A-Z])[^/]*'
```